# Synchronously run a logic and provide UI feedback in Command

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronous, maui

I do MAUI.NET application. I have a command that is going to invoke some heavy logic (could consume several seconds).

```
DoProcessingCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        IsProcessing = true;
        MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel = ServiceProvider.GetService<MainPageViewModel>();
        mainPageViewModel.ShowNextViewCommand.Execute(null);
        int a = Abc();
        IsProcessing = false;
        Success = a != 0;
    });

public int Abc()
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue / 2; i++)
        j++;
    return j;
}
```

Some explanation of details (I am not sure if that is matter): MainPageViewModel is registered as singleton in IoC container. I did not want to use shell for some reasons, and I made my own navigation in MainPageViewModel which is BindingContext for another singleton registered - MainPage. The latter one has `<ContentView Content="{Binding MainAreaView}"/>` which is a property that is set among others in ShowNextViewCommand. It works well.

Then I have few Views and in one of them I use this DoProcessingCommand which should put next view in the ContentView area and process the calculation. Until calculation is done, I would expect that the indicator would be shown. Because the next view contains:

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsProcessing}"/>
<VerticalStackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Success}">...</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The problem is that it stack for the time of processing on the previous view (the one from which the DoProcessingCommand is fired) and it repaints the next view with already VerticalStackLayout visible. The indicator is not shown, even for a part of a second...

What should I do to get expected results?

**edit**: That was quite easy actually... Just do a separate task and start it...

```
DoProcessingCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    IsProcessing = true;

    MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel = ServiceProvider.GetService<MainPageViewModel>();
    mainPageViewModel.ShowNextViewCommand.Execute(null);

    Task someProcessing = new(() =>
    {
        int a = Abc();
        IsProcessing = false;
        Success = a != 0;
    });
    someProcessing.Start();
});
```

Comment: `That was quite easy actually... Just do a separate task and start it`  You've solved the problem, right? Then you can posted an answer here so that others who have similar problems will get help from here. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Right, thank you sir, solution snippet provided!